# Awk statement to not working for colon symbol

Tags: awk

I am working on a AWK script which should replace the value of 3 column from an excel csv sheet to a particular value and the awk should ignore the first and the last line. 
The problem is with the string i am trying to update is causing issue, Below is the command i am using:

```
awk -v sq="'" -F, '
    t{print t} {a=t=$0}
    NR>2{$3=sqops_data<dbms=Teradata::instance=idw-prod>sq;t=$0}
    END {print a}
' OFS=, test1.csv
```

But, it is giving me syntax error at :: .

Sample CSV:

```
+++ Database Column - begin +++
Name,Host,Database,Database Schema,Database Table,Short Description,Long Description
CUST_ID,IDW-PROD,ops_data<dbms=Teradata::instance=pdw>,ops_data,D_FGHD_T,CUSTOMER IDENTIFIER,This field stores a unique value
+++ Database Column - end +++
```

Updating another scenario:
I happened to stuck in this. Wanted to update the third field to below value:

```
["LDGF","GHFT"]
```

tried below but it's only updating a blank [].

```
awk -v sq="" -F, 't{print t} {a=t=$0} NR>2{$3=sq"["LDGF","GHFT"]"sq;t=$0} END {print a}' OFS=, test2.csv
```

Also need to know how to update multiple columns in one statement.

Comment: Could you also post a sample of the csv?

Comment: Updated the csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To append/prepend the value of variable `sq` to **string** `ops_data<dbms=Teradata::instance=idw-prod>`, the latter must be quoted:

```
$3=sq"ops_data<dbms=Teradata::instance=idw-prod>"sq
```

or more readibly

```
$3 = sq "ops_data<dbms=Teradata::instance=idw-prod>" sq
```

Ex.

```
$ awk -v sq="'" -F, '
    t{print t} {a=t=$0}
    NR>2{$3=sq"ops_data<dbms=Teradata::instance=idw-prod>"sq;t=$0}
    END {print a}
' OFS=, test1.csv
+++ Database Column - begin +++
Name,Host,Database,Database Schema,Database Table,Short Description,Long Description
CUST_ID,IDW-PROD,'ops_data<dbms=Teradata::instance=idw-prod>',ops_data,D_FGHD_T,CUSTOMER IDENTIFIER,This field stores a unique value
+++ Database Column - end +++
```

Comment: Perfect!! Actually I wanted it to be without single quotes so i took sq="" and it worked!!

Comment: @user3901666 the whole `sq` thing is just a way to add single quotes within the single-quoted awk program - if you don't need that, you can remove both instances of `sq` (and the `-v sq="'"` assignment as well, if `sq` is used nowhere else)

Comment: Need your help in the updated case.

Comment: Nevermind i identified using hit and trials :)
awk -F, 't{print t} {a=t=$0} NR>2{$9="[\"PGFH\",\"ABCD\"]";t=$0} END {print a}' OFS=, test2.csv